# Issues with Vimeo SDK in Google Chrome on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change id's on a div once an embedded Vimeo video is played or paused. I followed this codepen to get started.
https://codepen.io/filipbech/pen/Aybku
Everything is working fine. Works on multiple browsers and with chrome developer. I push my changes and go to test on my Iphone. Suddenly, my code is working with all mobile browsers except Chrome.

Seemingly, the issue is with message.event, but because it works on desktop and all other mobile browsers, I cannot figure out what is happening. Below is my slightly modified code from the codepen link.

```
<script>
/* this version uses jquery, just to have easier clickhandlers and stuff - nothing that talks to vimeo is dependant on jQuery... */

var t;

/* Helper function to send a message to Vimeo-iframe */
function vimeoPost(action, value, target) {
    var data = { method: action };
    if (value) {
        data.value = value;
    }
    target.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), '*');
};

/* When a message is received, deal with it */
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  /* Get message and sender from the event */
  var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
  var sender = document.getElementById(message.player_id);

  /* If the message.event is "ready", then send a message to add eventlisteners for play and pause also */
  if(message.event == "ready") {
    vimeoPost('addEventListener','play',sender);
    vimeoPost('addEventListener','pause',sender);
  }

  /* Because of the above, we will start receiving events when video is played or paused - we will toggle a class, just to show it visually */ 
  if(message.event == 'play') {
    $('.vid').attr("id", "none");
    $('.item').attr("id", "dead");
    node = sender
    pE = node.parentElement
    parentElement = pE.parentElement
    parentElement.setAttribute("id","active");
    $('#tail').css('visibility', 'visible');
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        parentElement.setAttribute("id","none");
        $('#tail').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }, 3000);
  }
  if(message.event == 'pause') {
    clearTimeout(t); 
    sender.classList.remove('playing');
    sender.classList.add('paused');
    $('.item').attr("id", "dead");
    node = sender
    pE = node.parentElement
    parentElement = pE.parentElement
    parentElement.setAttribute("id","active");
        $('#tail').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }

}, false);
```

I'd expect this to be working, I have no idea what I need to fix. It's currently live at zakickes.com/mobile.html but it redirects to the mobile site regardless if you are on a phone. So far it works on mobile in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Upon further testing, I've found the above codepen example semi-functions in Chrome on mobile. If you click on the play button in the iframe, the class will not be added or removed, meaning the message.event function is not working via the iframe. However, if you click the play and pause buttons outside the iframe, the message.event will work as intended and add or remove the class successfully. 

What gives? Strange this works in all other browsers. I'd like to avoid using buttons, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't figure out why this code broke on Chrome Mobile, I did find a workaround - [Vimeo API not detecting play event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521855/vimeo-api-not-detecting-play-event)

```
var vPlayer1 = document.getElementById("video1");
var player1 = new Vimeo.Player(vPlayer1)

var vPlayer2 = document.getElementById("video2");
var player2 = new Vimeo.Player(vPlayer2)

player1.on('play', function() {
    console.log('played the 1 video!');
    vPlayer1.style.border = '10px solid red';
});
player2.on('play', function() {
    console.log('played the 2 video!');
    vPlayer2.style.border = '10px solid red';
});

player1.on('pause', function() {
    console.log('paused the 1 video!');
    vPlayer1.style.border = '10px solid blue';
});
player2.on('pause', function() {
    console.log('paused the 2 video!');
    vPlayer2.style.border = '10px solid blue';
});
```

Unfortunately this means hard coding each player one by one instead of having the messages take care of all existing players.